# Block in front of Google sheets aws

Tags: google-apps-script

I see that the cloud environment of aws has a blockage for inquiries to Google.
A message is received: "Sorry, unable to open the file at present."
Attached is a sample link:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1QEh8BnlNdnEvEG3fMv1Vo2EOCz_WL4nNAYt21trYXic/2/public/full?alt=json

When I try from somewhere else I get json
Is it possible to know the cause of the blockage in any aws environment?

{"version": "1.0", "encoding": "UTF-8", "feed": {"xmlns": "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "xmlns $ openSearch": "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/","xmlns$batch":"http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch","xmlns$gs":"http: //schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006","id":{"$t":"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1QEh8BnlNdnEvEG3fMv1Vo2EOCz_WL4nNAYt21trYXic/2/public/full"},"updated ": {" $ t ":" 2021-08-15T06: 46: 25.814Z "}," category ": [{" scheme ":" http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006 "," term ":" http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#cell "}]," title ": {" type ":" text "," $ t ":" Items "}," link ":

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It seems *all* access to JSON feeds of public Google Spreadsheet documents are no longer allowed, the API has been retired completely.

It seems like Google have suddenly blocked anonymous access to JSON feeds of public Google Spreadsheets documents. I note that, as of today:

- While the URL given in the question (https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1QEh8BnlNdnEvEG3fMv1Vo2EOCz_WL4nNAYt21trYXic/2/public/full?alt=json) does indeed work when opened in Chrome in a regular mode.
- It does NOT work in Chrome Incognito mode, and
- It does NOT seem to be downloadable via WGET